# VBA to replace WebService & FilterXML in Excel 2010 and older

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have created a Excel spreadsheet in Excel 2016 that uses WebService & FilterXML formulas to interface with Bing's API and drag data back from it. The formulas work great in Excel 2016 but when the spreadsheet is loaded in older versions of Excel 2010, etc it generates a #Name? error and does not return results. I believe this is because Webservice & FilterXMl formulas are not compatible with older versions of Excel.

Basically, the code should:

Take an API key from cell C2 in a sheet called Sheet2
Take the Start Location from cell C25 (this is variable and can be changed by the user)
Take the End Location from cell D25 (this is a variable and can be changed by the user)
Take the transport mode from cell C27 (this is a variable and can be changed by the user)
The URL should be shown in C29 (current code for this is: =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(distance.url,"$1",C25),"$2",D25),"$3",travel.mode),"$k",bingmaps.key)

This will generate a response in cell C31 - `i.e. the raw ouput (this is where WebService) is being used at the moment. Code is: =WEBSERVICE(C29)
This will generate a status code in cell C32 - i.e. 200 (this is where =FILTERXML(C31,"//StatusCode[1]" is being used at the moment)

=FILTERXML(C31,"//TravelDistance[1]") is then used in cell C34 to take the travel distance from C31
=FILTERXML(C31,"//TravelDuration[1]") is then used in cell C35 to show the duration from C31 in minutes

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Oh dear, I would guess it might be easier to just upgrade the old clients than trying to implement this reliably in older versions of Excel. I recall using the IE object in VBA some years ago. Wasn't very stable, but then I was loading a whole site not just an http get call.

Have a look here for some more in-depth info. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521876/calling-web-service-using-vba-code-in-excel-2010

An easier hack I employed recently was to pull web data straight into excel as a web data source (Data > From web). I dumped the whole html response from a twitter feed straight into a blank sheet, then used search and lookup formulas to find the row and column of data I wanted. I want to recall that I could even run a "text to columns" wizard automatically after a data refresh. This was all done without VBA, so no need for xlsm files and people being scared to enable macros.

Ps. I now tried to open that same sheet on my current computer (windows 10, office 2016) vs the old (windows 7, office 2010 or 13?). It complains about javascript being disabled in the browser (which I assume is internally still an internet explorer object and not edge).

Comment: Thank you for the response. Sadly upgrading isn't an option as some people are using newer Excel and some older. As there is other VBA code doing other things the cross compatibility is important here. Is there not a way to do this with VBA? I did try to do a XML dump but as the code is using Bing rest API, it wouldn't let me do this...I might have missed something so if this is doable happy to try but would need some guidance to make sure it's being done right and generating the correct information, I.e. duration and distance.

Comment: That link I posted contains several VBA solutions. Best to try a few and see what would work the best for your users and their software base.